# Redirect loop in GoDaddy web hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, website, godaddy

My friend has a domain (let's call it `myfriend.com`) registered in GoDaddy, he also uses GoDaddy's web hosting service.

The problem is, when we enter `http://myfriend.com/`

We got the following error message in Chrome:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://myfriend.com/XjLjQ/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

And we got this message from Firefox:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    *   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
          cookies.
```

Of course, we accept cookies (including third-party ones) in both browsers. And under the webroot, we do not have any `.htaccess` file.

So what could be the possible causes of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I would like to add that there is no `index.php` under the webroot.

Comment: This is unlikely to be a DNS issue, as DNS does not contain a mechanism to do redirects. My suggestion would be to fire up Fiddler (on Windows) or paros (on linux) and hit that page to help find out where the redirects are actually coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to involve your host in this, or post the content of the index.html (or whatever page it's trying to hit)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your going to have to log this with GoDaddy support, but you could try some of the following:

Upload a new html file, see if you can hit this directly, eg. upload test.html and try and hit myfriend.com/test.html  Does this work?

Install liveheaders on firefox, have a look at the requests, see if it's a 301/302 etc. Could also look at the developer tools in chrome.